# optimized Regular Expression in c# for searching multiline expression in Text

Tags: c#, regex, winforms

I am trying to find out following kind of expressions in a text file:

```
<&lt>[some text][newline][some text]<&gt;>
```

here the catch is that newlines can be many before we find end tag `<&gt;>`

I tried following regular expression

```
&lt;(.*?\n.*?)&gt;
```

it works perfectly to find expression divided by single line, but i need to also find expressions divided by various lines.

I tried following expression also:

`&lt;(.*?\n.*?)*&gt;`

but searching it is leading to timeout,
Please help?

Sample Text for searching:

```
<p class=3DMsoNormal style=3D'margin-top:12.0pt;margin-right:0cm;margin-bot=
tom:
0cm;margin-left:148.85pt;margin-bottom:.0001pt;text-indent:-148.85pt;
tab-stops:148.85pt right 16.0cm'><b style=3D'mso-bidi-font-weight:normal'><=
span
style=3D'font-family:"Calibri","sans-serif"'>RISK DETAILS<span style=3D'mso=
-tab-count:
1'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;=
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nb=
sp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;=
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; </span></span></b><span
style=3D'font-family:"Calibri","sans-serif"'>Your home is described as
&lt;q_1&gt;<o:p></o:p></span></p>

<p class=3DMsoNormal style=3D'margin-top:0cm;margin-right:0cm;margin-bottom=
:0cm;
margin-left:148.85pt;margin-bottom:.0001pt'><span style=3D'font-family:"Cal=
ibri","sans-serif"'>The
construction of your home is &lt;q_2&gt;<o:p></o:p></span></p>

<p class=3DMsoNormal style=3D'margin-top:0cm;margin-right:0cm;margin-bottom=
:0cm;
margin-left:148.85pt;margin-bottom:.0001pt'><span style=3D'font-family:"Cal=
ibri","sans-serif"'>The
main roof material is &lt;q_3&gt;<o:p></o:p></span></p>

<p class=3DMsoNormal style=3D'margin-top:0cm;margin-right:0cm;margin-bottom=
:0cm;
margin-left:148.85pt;margin-bottom:.0001pt'><span style=3D'font-family:"Cal=
ibri","sans-serif"'>Your
home was built in &lt;q_4&gt;<o:p></o:p></span></p>

<p class=3DMsoNormal style=3D'margin-top:0cm;margin-right:0cm;margin-bottom=
:0cm;
margin-left:148.85pt;margin-bottom:.0001pt'><span style=3D'font-family:"Cal=
ibri","sans-serif"'>Your
<span class=3DGramE>home &lt;q_5&gt; double</span> keyed deadlocks to all
external doors<o:p></o:p></span></p>

<p class=3DMsoNormal style=3D'margin-top:0cm;margin-right:0cm;margin-bottom=
:0cm;
margin-left:148.85pt;margin-bottom:.0001pt'><span style=3D'font-family:"Cal=
ibri","sans-serif"'>Your
home &lt;q_6&gt; keyed locks or grilles on all windows<o:p></o:p></span></p>

<p class=3DMsoNormal style=3D'margin-top:0cm;margin-right:0cm;margin-bottom=
:0cm;
margin-left:148.85pt;margin-bottom:.0001pt'><span style=3D'font-family:"Cal=
ibri","sans-serif"'>Your
home has &lt;q_7&gt; alarm installed<o:p></o:p></span></p>

<p class=3DMsoNormal style=3D'margin-top:0cm;margin-right:0cm;margin-bottom=
:0cm;
margin-left:148.85pt;margin-bottom:.0001pt'><span style=3D'font-family:"Cal=
ibri","sans-serif"'>Your
home &lt;q_8&gt; connected to mains water supply<o:p></o:p></span></p>
```

some examples:
Example 1:
Text to be searched:

```
 <span
      style=3D'color:blue'><o:p></o:p></span></span></p>
      </td>
      <td width=3D103 valign=3Dtop style=3D'width:77.5pt;padding:0cm 5.4pt 0cm =
    0cm'>
      <p class=3DMsoNormal align=3Dright style=3D'margin-top:3.0pt;margin-right=
    :0cm;
      margin-bottom:0cm;margin-left:0cm;margin-bottom:.0001pt;text-align:right;
      tab-stops:155.95pt'><span style=3D'font-family:"Calibri","sans-serif"'>&lt;=
    <span
      class=3DSpellE>spec_contents_value</span>&gt;<span style=3D'color:blue'><=
    o:p></o:p></span></span></p>
      </td>
     </tr>
    </table>

    <p class=3DMsoNormal style=3D'margin-top:0cm;margin-right:0cm;margin-bottom=
    :0cm;
    margin-left:148.85pt;margin-bottom:.0001pt;text-indent:-148.85pt;tab-stops:
    148.85pt right 453.55pt'><span style=3D'font-family:"Calibri","sans-serif"'=
    ><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></span></p>

    <p class=3DMsoNormal style=3D'margin-top:0cm;margin-right:0cm;margin-bottom=
    :0cm;
    margin-left:148.85pt;margin-bottom:.0001pt;text-indent:-148.85pt;tab-stops:
    148.85pt right 453.55pt'><span style=3D'font-family:"Calibri","sans-serif"'=
    >Unspecified
    Valuables<b style=3D'mso-bidi-font-weight:normal'><span style=3D'mso-tab-co=
    unt:
    1'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;=
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; </=
    span></b>&lt;valuables&gt;<o:p></o:p></span></p>

    <p class=3DMsoNormal style=3D'margin-top:0cm;margin-right:0cm;margin-bottom=
    :0cm;
    margin-left:148.85pt;margin-bottom:.0001pt;text-indent:-148.85pt;tab-stops:
    148.85pt right 453.55pt'><span style=3D'font-family:"Calibri","sans-serif"'=
    >Specified
    Valuables<b style=3D'mso-bidi-font-weight:normal'><span style=3D'mso-tab-co=
    unt:
    1'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;=
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nb=
    sp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; </span></b>&lt;<spanclass=3DSpellE>spec_valuables_ni</span>&gt;=
    <o:p></o:p></span></p>
```

I want my Regex.Match pattern to be able to search:

```
&lt;=
<span
  class=3DSpellE>spec_contents_value</span>&gt;
```

Or any of < ... > pattern spanning over more than one line. but not those present on same line.

Comment: format your code, so that we could provide the regex you want.

Comment: @mohits00691 is it &lt or < in your original code?

Comment: @nu11p01n73R your edits made it correct &lt only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use DOTALL modifier to make dot to match even line breaks (`\n`, `\r`).

```
(?s)&lt;(?:(?!&[gl]t;).)*?\n(?:(?!&[gl]t;).)*?&gt;
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/tW4tX3/2)

Comment: Hi @Avunash Raj first expression is working correctly, but it is also searching text without newline embedded, can there be some additions to it to make it search occurrences containing at-least one newline ?

Comment: It now skips few occurrences of &gt; , i have attached a sample text for searching on my Question.

Comment: Could you post the expected output?

Answer (score 1):

How about the regex

```
 &lt;[^&]*&gt;
```

for example http://regex101.com/r/iV9lS4/3

- `&lt;` matches `&lt;`
- `[^&]*` matches anything other than `&` including  newline
- `&gt;` matches `&gt;`

You can also use `.` to match anything by providing the DOTALL `(?s)` operator.

For the input

```
&lt;=
<span
  class=3DSpellE>spec_contents_value</span>&gt;
```

It would match as http://regex101.com/r/iV9lS4/4